# www to non-www, but for variable server_name

Tags: nginx

How can I redirect www requests to non-www with a wildcard `server_name`? It's simple if you know the address beforehand but can't find anything when the `server_name` is dynamic.

```
server {
    server_name www.*;
    return 301 $scheme://[???]$request_uri;
}
```

[???] is my question that normally be example.com for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) `server_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the regex named capture group:

```
server {
    server_name ~^www\.(?<basename>.*)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$basename$request_uri;
}
```